# Hide div withing iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-docs

I have an iframe and I'd like to hide a div whithin it, so bascily people can't for example sign out in the iframe.

What I did was :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeCSS(){
frame = document.getElementById("myIframe");
frame.document.getElementById("guser").style.display='none';
}
</script>

<iframe onload="javascript:changeCSS()" id="myIframe" src="{$docUrl}" width="800px" height="600px"></iframe>
```

But I can't get it to hide the div "guser".

If anyone could help I'd be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your example appears to be incomplete, the iframe is empty.

Comment: @dwb: It's not necessarily empty; that's determined by what's at the `src` URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `frame.contentWindow.document.getElementById` or `frame.contentDocument.getElementById`

Comment: I get:
Permission denied for <http://paginas.fe.up.pt> to get property HTMLDocument.document from <https://docs.google.com>.

Comment: If the domain is not one you own, then you cannot manipulate elements inside it. Your best attempt would be to make a proxy page that displays the iframed page and manipulates stuff.

Answer (score 0):

.style.visibility = "hidden";

Comment: Also tried that. I'm having the following error (indicated by firebug):
Permission denied for <http://paginas.fe.up.pt> to get property Window.document from <https://docs.google.com>.

Comment: Are you trying to access a window object from a different domain? Obviously nothing will work if you are. Perhaps the last comment in the next thread will help: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=189515

Answer (score 0):

[Different hostname or domain?](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy) **If you don't have control over the framed page, there's nothing you can easily do.** If you do have control over the framed page, try checking *inside* the frame whether the page is framed or not (this is based on a well-known frame-busting code):

```
function changeCSS() {
    document.getElementById("guser").style.display = 'none';
}

if(top != self) {
    if(window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load', changeCSS, false);
    } else {
        window.attachEvent('onload', changeCSS);
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Now that you mention Google Docs, I believe the above code won't work.